# How to come back to previous day?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, algorithm, datetime, time, activeadmin

On my activeadmin, i have to give hours of opening and closing to each shop.
For example, when a shop is open from 09 pm to 04 am, it's recorded as the same date.
But my algorithm has a malfunction

My algorithm is:

```
  def opened?
    today_day = Date.today.wday
    yesterday_day = today_day == 0 ? 6 : (today_day - 1)
    opening = self.openings.where(day: [today_day, yesterday_day]).first
    if opening
      opening_day = (Time.now).day
      if opening.closes_at < opening.opens_at
        opening_day = yesterday_day
      end
      # binding.pry
      today_opens_at = Time.new((Time.now).year, (Time.now).month, opening_day, opening.opens_at.hour, opening.opens_at.min)
      today_closes_at = Time.new((Time.now).year, (Time.now).month, (Time.now).day, opening.closes_at.hour, opening.closes_at.min)
      if today_opens_at < (Time.now) && (Time.now) < today_closes_at
        true
      else
        false
      end
    else
      false
    end
  end
```

I try to add gem activesupport for '1.day' but i have an error 'argument out of range'
I don't find the solution, can you help me quickly please?

Answer (score 0):

yerderday_day has to be a day of the month (0..30)

```
     today_day_of_week = Date.today.wday
     yesterday_day_of_week = today_day_of_week == 0 ? 6 : (today_day_of_week - 1)
     opening = self.openings.where(day: [today_day_of_week, yesterday_day_of_week]).first
     yesterday_day = Date.today.prev_day.day
```

or just replace this block:

```
  if opening.closes_at < opening.opens_at
    opening_day = Date.today.prev_day.day
  end
```

Comment: Opening in my active admin is a table, but in my code i have just model 'opening'

Comment: Could you post the model 'opening'?

Comment: model opening: " class Opening < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shop
  validates :day, inclusion: 0..6, presence: true
end
" Thanks you manfergo26 for your help

Comment: and the fields opens_at and closes_at?

Comment: Those fields are in opening but in db. Now I understand better the code. See my answer again. I edited and change some names you to understand whats happening.

Comment: I understand, but can i confirme to you tomorrow, because it's in after noon that i can be sure, but now i think that it's ok, i tell you if it's not good

Comment: Ok, thanks you, you think that you can help me for scraping with mechanize or not?

Comment: I dont understand whant you mean

Comment: I want to scrap a website, with mechanize

Comment: Ah ok, but you know scrap?

Comment: I dont think so, I just come here some time to help... and not very often.